# How to disable ssl plugin on MySQL 5.7 server?

Tags: centos, mysql

New introduced SSL connections on MySQL Server is now default installed on CentOS 6.7 default rep.

Just removing the certificate files can solve it accoding with Docs:

> *"If the server does not find valid certificate and key files in the data directory, it continues executing, but does not enable secure connections."*
>   Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html

But I want to fully disable SSL connections plugin on MySQL server, because I want to optimize the performance of MySQL server by removing everything that I am not using and this includes this plugin.

How to disable SSL on MySQL community server?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My test:

```bsh
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.7.12 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| have_openssl  | YES             |
| have_ssl      | YES             |
| ssl_ca        | ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                 |
| ssl_cert      | server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                 |
| ssl_crl       |                 |
| ssl_crlpath   |                 |
| ssl_key       | server-key.pem  |
+---------------+-----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit the config file: `/path/to/file/my.cnf`

```txt
[mysqld]
...

skip_ssl
# disable_ssl

...
```

```bsh
$ service mysql restart

$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.7.12 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| have_openssl  | DISABLED |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED |
| ssl_ca        |          |
| ssl_capath    |          |
| ssl_cert      |          |
| ssl_cipher    |          |
| ssl_crl       |          |
| ssl_crlpath   |          |
| ssl_key       |          |
+---------------+----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Worked like charm!. Thanks a lot

Comment: Tried to it `skip_ssl` to my conf file but that didn't work (likely my error). However I found it even easier to add it to the cli arguments of my SQL startup (in Docker) using the `--skip-ssl` flag